# Compare a double number to 1 and 0

Tags: c++, integer, double

How, how can I make this comparison for an if else?

```
if ((1 <= alpha <= 0) && (1 <= beta <= 0)) {
// Do something
}
```

Considering that alpha and beta are double variables.

Comment: Just use `&&`. and also write `1.0` and `0.0` to make it a float number

Comment: Are you trying to test that both variables are between 0 and 1 inclusive?  (The code, incorrect though it is, makes me think you are trying to test that the variables must be greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to zero - obviously impossible.)

Comment: `if (0 <= alpha && alpha <= 1 && 0 <= beta && beta <= 1)`

Comment: Could anyone of you give me a Skype? The code if for a triangle rasterization, where I calculate alpha, beta, gamma.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (1 <= alpha && alpha <= 0 && 1 <= beta && beta <= 0) {
// Do something
}
```

it has to work like this so each individual comparison can be converted to a boolean and then anded together.

Comment: `alpha` can't be greater than 1 and less than 0 at the same time.

Comment: This is always FALSE.

Comment: But the thing is, I need this for a triangle rasterization and on the slides it has:

if (0 < alpha < 1 and
 0 < beta < 1 and
 0 < gamma < 1 ) then
c = alpha c0 + beta c1 + gamma c2
drawpixel(x,y) with color c

Comment: @AlessiaFerroni Yeah, that's because the slides aren't written in C++. Converting it to C++, or C, or Java, or whatever your favourite language is is *your job*.

Comment: I know it is pseudocode, but I have tried t work on it, I got one part working but this other part is just giving me wrong results..

Comment: @AlessiaFerroni `if (0 < alpha < 1 and 0 < beta < 1 and 0 < gamma < 1 ) then` (which is what you want) is different to `if (1 < alpha < 0 and 1 < beta < 0 and 1 < gamma < 0 ) then` (which is what you are trying to code).  And in C++, etc, you need to say the equivalent of `if (0 < alpha and alpha < 1 and 0 < beta and beta < 1 and 0 < gamma and gamma < 1 ) then`.